# CSS/JS Reference Difference, Main Folder Vs Subfolder

Tags: javascript, css

I found that for files in my subfolders, I have to reference my CSS file as /1.css (otherwise it won't work) whereas in my main folder I can simply reference it as 1.css (no slash needed). This saves a small amount of space, but is it bad practice to reference it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path starting with "/" means "start from the root". Another way to solve this, which is usually more maintainable, is using a relative path. If the HTML is in a subfolder and the CSS is in the root folder, then the relative path to the CSS would be ../1.css

It means: go one folder up and find 1.css out there.

Comment: I understand that. I was just wondering if there's any reason not to just put 1.css (with no slash) if it's a file in the root folder (with the CSS also in the root folder).

Comment: If both files are in the root folder, then no need for prefixes. Did I understand you right?

Comment: Exactly, no need to /1.css you can just 1.css I'm just curious if there are any problems with doing it that way.

Comment: There's no problem with just writing `1.css`. On the contrary, relative paths are better, because if you move the entire file structure around, the paths will still work.